# Extra results when querying dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm so confused with this issue. I'm not sure what is causing so any guidance would be appreciated.

I have a dataframe and if I run the below command I get a list of tickers:

```
exchangeTickersDF.loc[exchangeTickersDF['Type'] == 'Common Stock']['ticker'].head(5)
0     AAB.TO
1     AAV.TO
2    ABCT.TO
3    ABST.TO
4     ABX.TO
Name: ticker, dtype: object
```

But if I run the same command via apply, I get:

```
def helloWorld(value):
  print(value)
exchangeTickersDF.loc[exchangeTickersDF['Type'] == 'Common Stock']['ticker'].head(5).parallel_apply(helloWorld)
AAB.TO
AAV.TO
ABCT.TO
ABST.TO
ABX.TO
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
Name: ticker, dtype: object
```

What makes it more confusing for me is if I just return None in my function, I still get results.

```
def helloWorld(value):
  return None
  # print(value)
exchangeTickersDF.loc[exchangeTickersDF['Type'] == 'Common Stock']['ticker'].head(5).apply(helloWorld)
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
Name: ticker, dtype: object
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is a common issue for apply ~

Comment: @BENY if this isn't me. I'm partly happy but partly annoyed. For the last 3 hours I thought I was going insane. It worked before then stopped..been reverting code and going nuts. What can I do?

Comment: What you would like to do ? ~\

Comment: @BENY I'm not sure, does it not have impact on my code? now you are making me think that I have another bug and incorrectly tagged it to this behaviour.

Comment: I think you want the first 5 items so you can print them one by one. You can do `hello_list = exchangeTickersDF.loc[exchangeTickersDF['Type'] == 'Common Stock']['ticker'].head(5).tolist()`. Then you can iterate thru that list and print them. If that's not what you want, then please clarify what you want to get done

Comment: remember, `print(value)` will print the value. However `print` function itself returns `None` if assigned to a variable. Your apply is requesting a return statement. Your print statement is resulting in a `return None`. That's why you get the printed lines and then the `None` 5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your code:

```
tmp_df = exchangeTickersDF.loc[exchangeTickersDF['Type'] == 'Common Stock']['ticker'].head(5)
# better written as
# tmp_df = exchangeTickersDF.loc[exchangeTickersDF['Type'] == 'Common Stock', 'ticker'].head(5)
```

Since `len(tmp_df)==5`,

```
tmp_df.apply(helloWorld)
```

will call `helloWorld` five times, one for each cell in `tmp_df`, then concatenate the **returns** of those function calls into a series.

Now,

```
def helloWorld(value):
  print(value)
```

print the `value` every time. So you see the first part of the function calls:

```
AAB.TO
AAV.TO
ABCT.TO
ABST.TO
ABX.TO
```

The second part, i.e. concatenation of the returns is:

```
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
Name: ticker, dtype: object
```

because your function `helloWolrd` doesn't return anything, which, in Python, means return `None`.

You would see it more clearly when you break the code even more:

```
# this wouldn't print the last part
out = tmp_df.apply(helloWorld)

# until you execute this
print(out)
```